# Inner elbow pain: Golfer's elbow or something else

Tags: injury

For the past few months I've been dealing with inner elbow and forearm pain that is brought on by pulling movements. My physio diagnosed me with  Golfer's elbow and has had me doing exercises to fix it for the past month. Since doing the exercises, the pain hasn't gotten better, which has made me start to think that my pain could be from something other than Golfer's elbow.

After watching this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXjaCsUlrZs) by Athlenex, I realised that it's not pulling movements per se that bring on the the pain, but rather the action of my index,pointer and ring fingers resisting upward motion (for example using those 3 fingers to push down on my traps). This isn't the same thing that's described in the video, but it's similar in that it's not golfer's elbow and that it involves the fingers.

So do you guys have any idea what it could be?

Comment: Maybe there's a way to re-phrase this question to not sound like asking for medical advice? It feels like some useful experience is not being shared, because people are afraid, that their sentences might be taken as medical advice, and understandably no one wants to get into trouble because of that.

Comment: Maybe I am naive....but why would any one smart enough to read a stack exchange site take an answer as actual medical advice, with all of the legal implications and authority implied by such advice.  Obviously the answer is probably from some random on the internet whose just trying to help.

Comment: I actually do think it's golfer's elbow. I think it hasn't healed because I keep aggravating it. I just need to take a few months off. I'm now convinced that tendonosis can heal, because I had it in my shoulder (which is notorious for never getting better) for 3 months, and it got better. It really did. It's as if I never had it now. Ah well, just another setback, but I'm pretty used to those by now.

Comment: Please take note that this is not an online forum for general discussion and sharing of experiences. There are plenty of them out there. This is a Q&A